# Why is top attribute not working with position relative?

Tags: html, css, css-position, vertical-alignment

I am trying to vertically align a div inside a div, and I used this tutorial:

```
.element
{
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

It worked on a div in a section above the one I'm currently working on. However, now top: 50% does nothing. Why is that?

This is the code:

```html
<div id="venuerow" class="clearfix row" style="position: relative;">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6" 
        style="position: relative; top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%);">
        center this
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
        1<br>
        2<br>
        3<br>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here, I expect top: 50% to push my inner div down so it starts from the middle of the outside div, and then transform should move it up for half of inner div's height.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: It works. Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/561jxhrj/)

Comment: The outer element has (the default) `height: auto` and `50%` of `auto` is `0`.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much!

Comment: @alirezasafian, would you mind putting your comment as the answer to this question?

Comment: I'll do as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works. Try this:
[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/561jxhrj/)

```css
 html,
 body,
 #venuerow {
   height: 100%;
   text-align: center;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="venuerow" class="clearfix row" style="position: relative;">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6" style="position: relative;
             top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%);">
    center this
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @ivanacorovic The answer is added.